# How to dynamically add input form?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to dynamically add input forms when "New Item" is clicked. But not really know how to write the code in the js part. Any idea?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>Angular - My Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

  <body>
    <h1>My Notes</h1>
    <div ng-controller="Note">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Question">
      <input ng-class="{'blockInput': !inlineChecked}" type="text" placeholder="enter text...">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline" ng-model="inlineChecked"> Inline
      <br>
      <button ng-click="add()">New Item</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var Note = function($scope){
        // create a variable contain new input forms?? 
      }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 34):

Use an array and ngRepeat...

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>Angular - My Notes</title>

  <body>
    <h1>My Notes</h1>
    <div ng-controller="Note">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.questionPlaceholder}}" ng-model="item.question">
        <input ng-class="{'blockInput': !item.inlineChecked}" type="text" placeholder="enter text..." ng-model="item.text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="inline" ng-model="item.inlineChecked"> Inline
      </div>
      <button ng-click="add()">New Item</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var Note = function($scope){
        $scope.items = [];

        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            inlineChecked: false,
            question: "",
            questionPlaceholder: "foo",
            text: ""
          });
        };
      }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JsBin... http://jsbin.com/fusapojo/4/edit?html,output

Comment: A little bit more will need to be added (ng-model on inputs). For example, in you jsBin add `{{ items | json }}` and fill in some of the form and you'll see :)

Comment: @Asok how to edit the placeholder value by angularjs?

Comment: @Asok Thanks. I didn't want to add more than was needed to the original. Updated now.  :)

Comment: @user3112938 You want a dynamic placeholder? I'll add an answer showing a way to do it, but Anthony's should be the one that is accepted. I was going to type it in here but it's too much text.

Comment: @anthonychu +1, would you like to take the dynamic placeholder question or shall I?

Comment: @Asok Do you know how to If user click submit, a JSON must be print out on the bottom of the display note following this format:

[ 
{
“question”: “Write down Nhat’s email”,
 “answer”: “nhat@taie.com.au”,
 “inline”: true
},
{
<% NEXT QUESTION/ANSWER %>
},
{
<%…%>
}
]

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="flavour in flavours" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" ng-model="flavour.name">
        </div>                
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:
$scope.flavours = [];

```
$scope.addFlavour = function () {
    $scope.flavours.push({ 
        name: "",
        pg: 100,
        vg: 0,
        quantity: 5.0
    });
}
```